# Регулярные выражения JS | Найти подстроку в строке

Tags: javascript

Есть строка:

`let url = "http://любой_домен/filter?size=M&color=1&color=2&manufacturer=aaa&manufacturer=ddd"`

Используя метод `match` хочу найти подстроку. Где находится слово `color`. На выходе должен получиться массив, который будет содержать в себе `color=1` & `color=2`.

```js
let color = url.match(/color\=\S+?&?/i)
```

Эта запись возвращает, только первое совпадение `color=1`.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, для вашего случая надёжнее использовать не регулярки, а специально предназначенные для парсинга адресов средства ([URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) и [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)):

```js
const urlString = "https://example.org/filter?size=M&color=1&color=2&manufacturer=aaa&manufacturer=ddd";

const url = new URL(urlString);

console.log(url.searchParams.getAll('color'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let url = 'http://любой_домен/filter?size=M&color=1&color=2&manufacturer=aaa&manufacturer=ddd';
let color = url.match(/color\=\S+?&?/ig);
console.log(color);
```

Comment: Наверное, чуть надёжднее и точнее будет `/\bcolor\=[^&]+/ig`

Comment: @vsemozhebuty я просто добавил  `g`, ничего больше не трогал :)